# Extract text from XML file

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

i'm trying to extract data from a XML file with a Python script but I can't get it to go deep enough. I succeeded to extract 'updated' and 'published' categories for instance but not the rest. I'm particularly interested into extracting alt1 and alt2.

Here is the structure of the xml file :

```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:as="http://atomserver.org/namespaces/1.0/">
        <id>/electron/atom/v1/domesday/dblocks-CI-52-54/CI-522000-5473000.xml</id>
        <as:revision>0</as:revision>
        <updated>2011-04-29T11:40:19.000Z</updated>
        <published>2011-04-29T11:40:19.000Z</published>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <block xmlns="">
                <alt1>Some text</alt1>
                <alt2>Some other thext</alt2>
            </block>
        </content>
    </entry>
```

And here is what I tried so far :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(filename)
root = tree.getroot()
alt1elt = root.findtext('content/dblock/alt1')
alt2elt = root.findtext('content/dblock/alt2')
print(alt1elt)
print(alt2elt)
```

It prints

```
None
None
```

and not the two strings I'm trying to get. Do you have any idea what could solve this ?

Comment: What's the problem with your current code?

Comment: @SebastianHofmann It prints None, and not really the text I want to extract (namely 'Some text' and 'Some other text')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from xml.dom import minidom

doc = minidom.parse("yourxmlfile.xml")

print(doc.getElementsByTagName("alt1")[0].firstChild.data)
print(doc.getElementsByTagName("alt2")[0].firstChild.data)
```

Example of extracting the data using minidom.

Comment: Nice, thanks for your message, it helps a lot! But now I having an other issue with this kind of extraction. I want to extract text from <content> wich is a child of an <content> tag. What should I change in the getElementBytagName query ?

Comment: content = doc.getElementsByTagName("content")
print(content[1].firstChild.data)     This saves all elements with the <content> tag in a list, the <content> inside the <content> is the second element in the list.